# Sometimes can't scroll my iOS Safari web app

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, safari

You can see an example of my web app here:

https://arep.co/g/giveaway-test-do-not-delete/

The web app is structured like this:

[image: Web App screen shot]

There is a *fixed footer*, which currently has the text "Enter competition" and a countdown. I'm calling the section of the web app that is *not* the *fixed footer* the *main section*.

There are a couple of things happening (which may be related to each other):

1. Scrolling the *main section* sometimes stops working when the "focus" changes from the *main section* to the *fixed footer*. I'm using the term "focus" loosely because I don't think its the right terminology but I'm unsure what word to use here.
2. When this happens you can get scrolling working again by **tapping** on the *main section* to change "focus" -- after which it starts scrolling again. But sometimes you have to reload the page and then scrolling magically works again.
3. When the page first loads, *sometimes* the scrolling of the *main section* doesn't work at all, its locked, and you can't get it to scroll again without reloading the page or clicking on the "Enter competition" button.

**How to reproduce**

This is the tricky part, because its a little hard to repro:

1. Sometimes, when you first load the web app you can't scroll the *main section*. If you reload the page then it works fine, or if you click on the "Enter competition" to force Safari to redraw the bkgrd (it pops up a modal) then scrolling starts to work again. OR if you re-orient the phone so you change from portrait to landscape and back to portrait to force Safari to redraw the DOM the focus changes back to the *main section* naturally and you can then scroll it again.
2. If you start scrolling on the *main section* and then move your thumb down so that it lifts off the *fixed footer* you can get scrolling to a pt where it stops responding properly and you have to wait a few seconds for "something" (not sure what) and then scrolling starts again properly.

I have to say scrolling in iOS Safari is a giant *mega* PITA! I haven't had any of these problems on Android -- the webview component is so buggy.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my site, and I believe it is related to using `position:fixed`. Also, this seems to be a pure CSS problem and has nothing to do with JavaScript. I have found very little information on this as unfortunately there used to be even worse problems circa iOS5 and those seem to dominate all search results...

Comment: Having the same issue...